# relative divs in a fixed wrapper

Tags: css

I have a wrapper with absolute positioing and a bunch of divs inside it:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="f inactive" style="width:12.5%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222223%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222223%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222223%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222223%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222227%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222227%"></div>
    <div class="f" style="width:9.722222222222227%"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}


i {
    background-color: #83b209;
    width: 100%;
}

div.f {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #83b209;
}

div.f.inactive {
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbfLwdq/). As you can see, for some reason the wrapper is bigger than the inner divs when I want it to be same height as inner divs. You shouldn't be able to see the black bacground...

Comment: `display: inline-block;` is causing this, use `float: left;` instead. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbfLwdq/2/) or put the `font-size` on the wrapper. This will also solve the problem. [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbfLwdq/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `line-height` to `0` in your wrapper to solve this.

```
.wrapper {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `height: 12px;` on your `.wrapper` and put `height: 100%;` on your `div.f`

Comment: can you please add more details to your answer or format a bit or a working fiddle so that it gives a proper answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've [updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbfLwdq/1/) by setting a height on the wrapper and matching that in your divs.

Does that achieve what you wanted?

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="f inactive" style="width: 12.5%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222223%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222223%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222223%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222223%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222227%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222227%"></div>
        <div class="f" style="width: 9.722222222222227%"></div>
    </div>

.wrapper {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0px;
background-color: #000;
padding:0;
margin:0;

height:15px;
}


i {

background-color: #83b209;
width: 100%;
}

div.f {
font-size: 0;
height: 15px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #83b209;
}

div.f.inactive {
background: red;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just write this little answer.

`display: inline-block;` is causing this problem. You may want to go read up about what it does but you look like you have tried to solve it by keeping the `<i></i>` together and using `font-size: 0;`. Clearly not working for you tho.

So solution one, is to put `font-size: 0;` on the wrapper as you have it to low to affect the output.

**CSS:**

```
.rangeslider-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #000;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbfLwdq/3/)

---

Another solution is to use `float: left;` and not bother with `display: inline-block;`.

**CSS:**

```
.rangeslider .rangeslider-bg i {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 12px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cwbfLwdq/2/)